# Node JS Async Map is synchronous or asynchronous call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

When i am trying with the Node js Async Module functions like waterfall, mapSeries etc, most of them are asynchronous in nature. But looks like async map is not asynchronous. For example, i tried this one:

```
var async = require('async');

console.dir('This is the begining of the program');
async.mapSeries([6,7,8,9], justAddOne, asyncMapCompleted);
function justAddOne(number, callback) {
    callback(null, ++number);
}

function asyncMapCompleted(error, result) {
  console.log("map completed. Error: ", error, " result: ", result);
}

async.map([1,2,3,4,5], justAddOne, asyncMapCompleted);

console.dir('This is the end of the program');
```

I got the following output:

```
'This is the begining of the program'
map completed. Error:  null  result:  [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
'This is the end of the program'
map completed. Error:  null  result:  [ 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

We can see from the output, when we call async.map function, the execution thread stops their until it is completed (we got output "'This is the end of the program'" after async map).

But, we called the async mapSeries at the beginning of the program, it does not stop execution but, prints the results after the 'end program' message.

So, async.map is a synchronous call?  I tried to check in documentation but unable to find it.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here about what async.js IS. It is not a library to create async functions. It is a library for you to process functions that are already async with loop-like constructs. Basically, it is control structures for async code, similar to what promises do (note: promises are also not intended to make your code async, only to allow you to work with async code when you need to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source, [`async.eachOf`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L224-L249) (called from `map`) isn't doing anything that would make it async, where [`async.eachOfSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L252-L282) (called from `mapSeries`) uses `async.setImmediate` internally.

Comment: Gresak, I voted you. You are right, in "async.js" file,  async.eachOfSeries function which is called for the mapSeries sets the  Immediate, while eachOf (for async.map) is not.

Comment: Gresak please wait, i will mark it. In the mean while, please look at the Paulpro comment, it seems interesting.

Comment: @user3278897 I did, he's basically suggesting the same as `async.mapSeries` is doing for you already.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether or not you call `callback` synchronously or not. You can make sure it's asynchronous by using [ensureAsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#ensureAsync):

```
async.map([1,2,3,4,5], async.ensureAsync( justAddOne ), asyncMapCompleted);
```

Comment: Wow, @Paulpro this worked. But i have a question for you. See the async.js file (Github), async map is not set  Immediate, but ensureAsync is setImmediate, So my question is, if we set the parameter function as asynchronous and the main method which called is synchronous (here, async.map), then how does it is working.

Comment: @user3278897 Did Marko's explanation satisfy you or do you still have questions about this?